# Moving multiple nodes with Gephi

Tags: gephi

I am having a hard time dragging multiple nodes on the screen with Gephi. The multi-select button allows me to select multiple nodes but not move them on the screen. Could this be a system issue (running Ubuntu on Mac)? I have searched the web but to no avail. Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To drag multiple nodes in Gephi, use the cylinder tool, which is part of the Dragging tool (Fist icon).

- While the Dragging tool is selected, in the top left of the Graph window, next to the word "Dragging," click the blue word (Configure) as shown below
- Set the diameter to something greater than one, and you'll see a grey disc that allows you to drag all nodes that are within the disc.
- To "close" the tool, i.e. restore it to 1-pixel Dragging, Configure the diameter back to 1.

[image: Gephi cylinder tool]

Comment: size of the cylinder can be changed by ctrl+middle mouse wheel.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use the cylinder tool - http://forum.gephi.org/viewtopic.php?t=20.  Make sure to set the diameter to something bigger than one, and you'll see a circle that allows you to select multiple nodes within its boundaries.